# 500 internal server error в проекте asp.net mvc при отправке формы

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Index.cshtml:

```html
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<td class="big_card" colspan="3">
    <form onsubmit="return false" action="/Home/Index" method="POST">
        <fields>
            <p > Оформление заказа</p>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required /><br />

            <input type="tel" name="Tel" placeholder="Введите номер телефона в формате 8-ххх-ххх-хххх" required patern="8-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" /><br />

            <select name="Car" required>
                <option value="Ghibili">Ghibili</option>
                <option value="Quattroporte">Quattroporte</option>
                <option value="GranTurismo">GranTurismo</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </fields>
    </form>
</td>
```

HomeController:

```html
   // GET: Home
        private Models.ShopDBEntities db = new Models.ShopDBEntities();

       
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Items = db.Cars;
            return View(Items);
        }

     

        [HttpPost]

       public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Tel, int Car)
        {
            Order order = new Order
            {
                UserName = Name,
                UserTel = Tel,
                CarId = Car,
                Status = "Создана"

            };
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        } 

    }
```

scrypts.js:

```js
/*Практика JavaScript*/
function SetIMG(selected_url)
{
   var item = document.getElementById("Preview");
    item.src=selected_url;
}
/*Практика jQuery*/
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#header').fadeTo(2000,0.3,function(){ 
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top }, 2000);
   });
});

/*Ajax jQuery*/
$(document).on('submit','form',function(){
    
    var UserName=$('input[name=Name]').val();
    var UserTel=$('input[name=Tel]').val();
    var Car=$('select').val();
    //Валидация введенных данных.
    //Проверяем имя
    if(UserName.length>0)
    {
    //Проверяем номер телефона
    var regular=/^\8-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/;
    if(regular.test(UserTel)==true)
    {
        alert('Всё норм!');
     SubmitForm(UserName,UserTel,Car);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Вы неверно указали номер телефона");
    }
    }
    else{
        alert("Вы забыли указать имя");
    }
});

/*Ajax jQuery*/
function SubmitForm(name,tel,car)
{
   $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/Home/Index",
  data: { Name: name, Tel: tel, Car:car }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Отлично: " + msg );
  }).fail(function() {
    alert( "При передачи данных произошла ошибка" );
  }); 
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Maserati</title>
    <link href="/Content/CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="/Content/JS/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/Content/JS/scrypts.js"></script>-
</head>
<body>
   
               @RenderBody()
   
</body>
</html>
```

Должно добавлять данные в таблицу dbo.Orders:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему в Layout.cshtml и в скрине index стоят тэги <html> и тд? у вас в коде  подсвечено же этот тэг

Comment: @Andrew_Romanuk, а в чем проблема поставить точку остановки в метод `Index()` для POST-запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас из select переменная car будет иметь тип string, так как:

```
  <option value="Ghibili">Ghibili</option>
```

а в post методе вы пытаетесь получить int

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Tel, int Car)
```

замените value в select на Id'шки и все будет работать